# What version of Python should I use if I'm a new to Python?

Tags: python, windows, linux, macos

I am now on the road to learn Python (not the first time I wanted to get this done) now I am standing in front of a decision which I am not able to make so easily

Which Version should I use?!

I found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090820/what-version-of-python-should-i-use-if-im-a-new-to-python) question was asked about a year ago and Python 2.6 was chosen (more or less) now whats the status quo now ?!

I am running my home and business environment mixed with Windows (XP, 7, 2003, 2008), Linux (Ubuntu Intel & PPC) and Mac OS X (PPC & Intel) Environments and my first approach is to learn the language by creating few scripts to help me do my job as a network administrator and server administrator.

Thanks for your help, by the way I am not new in programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For writing admin scripts, I would recommend the current Python 3.x variant and http://diveintopython3.org. As you already know how to program, you will pick up the differences between 3.x and 2.x rather easily in case you should need a 2.x-only library.

For your purposes, the major difference between 2.x and 3.x are likely `print` being a function  (3.x) vs. a special command (2.x) and strings that are always unicode (3.x) vs. special unicode-strings (2.x).

Comment: I decided to start with version 3 - I am new and till the time a manage to be good in python a lot of stuff will be ported.

Answer (score 3):

for real projects: 2 (many libs are incompatible with 3), for small scripts and learning: 3.

Answer (score 1):

I'd favour 2.7 at the moment.

There are more libraries available for 2.7, and new features are still being added.

Answer (score 0):

It's still Python 2.x, but 2.7 should serve your needs now. Python 3 is still some way off comprehensive support from the universe of tools, libraries and frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Python as well...for what i've read, 2.7 is the one, but i had to downgrade to 2.5 to be able to use Google App Engine's SDK.