# Which python should you use for new projects in 2017?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090820/what-version-of-python-should-i-use-if-im-a-new-to-python) asked in 2010 says "use python 2".

Seven years later, what's the best python to use for new projects, 2.7 or 3.6?

Comment: I didn't downvote but I suspect that it's probably due to this being opinion based. If you stated your requirements there maybe a concrete reason to prefer one over the other, for instance library support may determine preferring one over the other

Comment: On a lighter note, `random.choice(['2.7', '3.6'])`

Comment: even it's still opinion based - I would say reality - reading official documents makes it reality based - python 2 will run out of support in 2020 - so you don't want to start your project in python 2 knowing that in 3 years you will have to rewrite it ... I like that random choice comment :)

Answer (score 5):

I think it's a good article why you should choose python 3:
[Python 3 vs Python 2](https://www.activestate.com/blog/2017/01/python-3-vs-python-2-its-different-time)

> "The official end-of-life date for the Python 2 series is 2020 which means you have three years of support from the community. After that, you'll have to find ways to get support for this series as new vulnerabilities can always arise. Since 2.7.13 is expected to be the last major release in the 2.7 series, new features won’t be backported, and only security and bug fixes will be going in from now until 2020. (ActiveState will continue to support the Python 2 series for a very long time, but new language features will be only available in Python 3.)
>
> In addition to the reasons mentioned above, you want to move to Python
>   3 because there have been a lot of improvements in the language.
>   Probably the biggest reason is integer division which is much simpler
>   and stronger in Python 3. Other reasons include asynchronous support,
>   better exception handling, Unicode support, and you can mix tabs and
>   spaces. Python 3 also gives you function annotations and range memory
>   objects which are significantly more memory efficient."

And in 2009 the official documentation said Python 2.5 was 10% faster then 3.0 : [Offical Documentation](https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#performance)

> "The net result of the 3.0 generalizations is that Python 3.0 runs the pystone benchmark around 10% slower than Python 2.5. Most likely the biggest cause is the removal of special-casing for small integers. There’s room for improvement, but it will happen after 3.0 is released!"

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon, could you include the meat of what those links state, thanks

Comment: @EdChum I edited my answer, I hope It's okay now